# How can a neural network get unstuck from a local minimum?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

Since, there are so many local minimums in so complex neural network function, it is common for a neural network to get stuck on a local minimum. How will the neural network get **unstuck** from that local minimum.

[image]

Comment: We use momentum-based optimization techniques to avoid local minimums. Some other variants of momentum-based optimizers are available which solve the problem of overshooting the global minimum. Refer [this](https://blog.paperspace.com/intro-to-optimization-momentum-rmsprop-adam/).

Comment: every once in a while introduce noise to jolt the optimizer out of its comfort zone

Answer (score 1):

In various ways suchs as

- **momentum**: think of momentum as a means of dampening oscillations and speeding up the iterations, leading to faster convergence. This means replacing gradients with a leaky average over past gradients.
- **sparse features and preconditioning** (Adagrad): decrease the learning rate dynamically on a per-coordinate basis. This means, use the magnitude of the gradient as a means of adjusting how quickly progress is achieved - coordinates with large gradients are compensated with a smaller learning rate.
- **RMSProp**: a combination of momentul and adagrad, combining leaky averages and coefficient-wise preconditioner
- Adadelta: The learning rate cannot be parameterised but rather adapts itself given rate of change in the model parameters
- **Adam**: a great algorithm that summarises features from all of the above
- **Scheduling**: decreasing the learning rate during training

sources: https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/, https://d2l.ai/chapter_optimization